# In NodeJS how do I wait for stripe API await to return price object before assigning value to object variable and pushing to array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am trying to use a for loop retrieve a price ID from stripe API for each item in the `userItems` array

```
[
    {
      quantity: '1',
      stripe_id: 'prod_IlBmZ4z2QNWeDb',
      stripe_price_id: 'price_1I9fOWLY0lC869vlVNfnYqT3',
      printful_id: '211335091',
      external_id: '6000dcdfa3b443'
    }
  ]
```

However I'm stuck in the temporal dead zone, causing me to retrieve a "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'price' before initialization" error

I believe its because `item` is being declared before stripe API returns with the`price` object

How do I wait until stripe returns with `item` before assigning `price.unit_amount` to object variable and pushing it to `lineItems` array?

I've been fiddling around with promise syntax trying to solve this but I've been having trouble grasping promises/async/await (especially in context of the stripe API, where the docs don't really touch on this kind of nuance) so I'm pretty stumped

Here's my current code

```
router.post('/create-session', async (req, res) => {
    if (Array.isArray(req.body) == false) {
        var userItems = [req.body];
    } else {
        var userItems = req.body;
    }
    console.log(userItems)
    const lineItems = [];
    const metaData = []
    var i;
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < userItems.length; i++) {
            const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(
                userItems[i].stripe - price - id
            );
            var item = {
                quantity: userItems[i].quantity,
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product: userItems[i].stripe_id,
                    unit_amount: price.unit_amount
                }
            }

            //   var itemMetaData = {
            //       variant_id: userItems[i].printful-id,
            //      external_id: userItems[i].external-id
            //  } */
            //lineItems.push(item)
            // metaData.push(itemMetaData)

        }
        //create checkout session
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            billing_address_collection: 'auto',
            shipping_address_collection: {
                allowed_countries: ['US'],
            },
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: lineItems,
            //   metadata: metaData,
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: `http://localhost:5000/success.html`,
            cancel_url: `http://localhost:5000/cancel.html`,
        });
        res.json({
            //return session ID
            id: session.id
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, your code works perfectly on my end. If possible could you share how you're initializing stripe-node?

Comment: Odd, It must have something to do with the function inside the endpoint or the if statement . I've added those as well.

Comment: That all seems sound to me. Does the error message come with a stack trace? It should point to the file and line that the error occurred on.

Comment: Yeah, 31:37. I wonder if its not executing the if'then statement before the try/for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to using the price variable in your expression before the variable is initialized. Did you mean to use `userItems[i].price`?

```
try {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < userItems.length; i++) {
        const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(
            userItems[i].stripe - userItems[i].price - userItems[i].id
        );
        var item = {
            quantity: userItems[i].quantity,
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product: userItems[i].stripe_id,
                unit_amount: price.unit_amount
            }
        }
        lineItems.push(item)
    }
    //create checkout session
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        billing_address_collection: 'auto',
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['US'],
        },
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: lineItems,
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `http://localhost:5000/success.html`,
        cancel_url: `http://localhost:5000/cancel.html`,
    });
    res.json({
        //return session ID
        id: session.id
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: negative, I've edited post to show what data userItems contains. The goal is to retrieve price.unit_amount from Stripe API for each item in the array. The example only has one but the array + for loop is for if the customer has multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had

```
   const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(
                userItems[i].stripe-price-id
             );
```

Instead of

```
   const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(
                userItems[i].stripe_price_id
             );
```

Thank you all, I will scurry away so I can take my large, voluminous brain and proceed to bask in my superior IQ